# Conditional rendering inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of buttons in a array

```
  const menuItems = [
      {
        key: "delete",
        title: "Delete Order",
        showFor: "all",
      },
      {
        key: "cancel",
        title: "Cancel Order",

        showFor: "all",
      },
      {
        key: "confirm",
        title: "Confirm Order",

        showFor: "unconfirmed",
      },
    ];
```

Now what i want to render it conditionally,for example i will check if the current state of the component and then render it accordingly.
For example in confirmed order want to show only the delete and cancel not the confirm one.
But for unconfirmed order i want to show all them of them.

Currently i am doing like this

```
   {currentTable === "notconfirmed"
          ? menuItems.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Menu.Item key={item.key}>
                    <div>{item.title}</div>
                  </div>
                </Menu.Item>
              );
            })
          : menuItems
              .filter((item) => item.showFor != "unconfirmed")
              .map((kk) => {
                return (
                  <Menu.Item key={kk.key}>
                    <div>
                      <div>{kk.title}</div>
                    </div>
                  </Menu.Item>
                );
              })}
```

It is working fine but this looks really messy any clean way of doing this?

Comment: The `map` code is common. So, get an array based on the condition first: `const array = condition ? menuItems : menuItems.filter(..)`. And then use `array.map(..)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add conđition in map like this:

```
{menuItems.map((item) => {
      if (
        currentTable !== "notconfirmed" &&
        item.showFor === "unconfirmed"
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      return (
        <Menu.Item key={item.key}>
          <div>{item.title}</div>
        </Menu.Item>
      );
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that is the way it done.

You can refactor your code moving the render logic of each block into a function or a component to make it more clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to refact the data... It's not a good idea to have the filter logic in the data... The property `showFor` seems like [Code Smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

But there is an example to improve your code.

If you wanna keep your `filter` function, you use something like:

```
const component = (menuItems, currentTable = "notconfirmed") => {
    const filterValue = currentTable === "notconfirmed" 
    
    return <>
        {menuItems.filter((item) => filterValue ? item.showFor === "unconfirmed" : item.showFor !== "unconfirmed").map((filterdItem) => (
            <Menu.Item key={filterdItem.key}>
                <div>
                    <div>{filterdItem.title}</div>
                </div>
            </Menu.Item>
        ))}
    </>
}
```

In order to avoid the filter to make less operations and optimize your code, it's a better option:

```
const component = (menuItems, currentTable = "notconfirmed") => {
    const filterValue = currentTable === "notconfirmed" ? "all" : "unconfirmed"
    
    return <>
        {menuItems.map((filterdItem) =>
        (
            filterdItem === filterValue && <Menu.Item key={filterdItem.key}>
                <div>
                    <div>{filterdItem.title}</div>
                </div>
            </Menu.Item>
        ))}
    </>
}
```